# Create token of stripe in xamarin android giving exception?

Tags: xamarin.android, stripe-payments

I am integrating stripe payment with my xamarin android application.
But when I am creating token in try block, its giving exception.
Why its giving exception?
Here is my code I am doing :

```
var card = new Card
        {
            Number = "4242424242424242",
            ExpiryMonth = 12,
            ExpiryYear = 16,
            CVC = "123"
        };

var token = await StripeClient.CreateToken(card, "pk_test_lkH9OCXVwDdJzTzc9kI8UILY");
await CreateBackendCharge(token);

async Task CreateBackendCharge(Token token)
    { 
        var http = new HttpClient();

        var content = new StringContent("StripeTokenId=" + token.Id);

        var response = await http.PostAsync("https://stripe.com/token", content);
    }
```

Exception is

```
Not Flagged [1] Line 83 {System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:882 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002af] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:363 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Stripe.StripeClient+<requestToken>c__async2.MoveNext () [0x00085] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Stripe.StripeClient+<CreateToken>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x001c4] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at AndroidApp.MainActivity+<OnCardDataRecieved>d__8.MoveNext () [0x00095] in C:\Users\karanveer.READINKAD\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AndroidApp\AndroidApp\MainActivity.cs:74 }
```

Comment: you should post the exception you are seeing as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Error: NameResolutionFailure` means that your code was unable to resolve a domain name -- likely the domain name you use in your `StripeClient.CreateToken` method.

By the way, the rest of the code has no chance of working. Even if you succeed in creating a token, POSTing a token to `https://stripe.com/token` will result in a 404 error since there is nothing at that URL.

I recommend you take some time to browse through Stripe's [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs), and in particular how to [create charges](https://stripe.com/docs/charges) using tokens.

Comment: Thanks for reply, See error is in 'https://stripe.com/token' url or any where else

Comment: And i am using this documentation https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/stripe please tell what is wrong

Comment: @Karan I don't have experience with Xamarin, but the documentation you linked looks correct. After creating the token, you need to send it to your own backend server (in the doc, it's `https://example.com/token`) so you can use it in a charge creation request. This tutorial explains how to create charges: https://stripe.com/docs/charges